# Индикатор загрузки для QX11EmbedContainer

Tags: gui, qt4

Возникла необходимость отображать прелоадер, пока в контейнер `QX11EmbedContainer` не встроится виджет. Момент начала отображения предзагрузчика есть, по сигналу `clientIsEmbedded()` я могу определить момент встраивания и прекратить показ прелоадера, также прекратить показ в случае ошибки. Но возник вопрос - какими средствами лучше отображать сам прелоадер?
Если я правильно понимаю, `QSplashScreen` не подходит, т.к. он привязан к виджету.
`QProgressBar` - непонятно, как устанавливать процент выполнения операции.
Показывать виджет с `*.gif` в виде `QMovie`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет необходимости в определении процентов выполнения операции, то можно спокойно показывать анимированное изображение. Как пример:

```
m_pProgressText = new QLabel("Загрузка...", this);
m_pProgressImage = new QLabel(this);
QMovie* movie = new QMovie(":/icon/throbber.gif");
m_pProgressImage->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

При этом при переносе приложения на Windows обязательно должна быть библиотека qgif4.dll, иначе изображение не будет отображаться.

Comment: спасибо. так пробовал, все работает, но непонятно, куда этот прелоадер поместить. Есть QMainWindow, в нем есть QMdiArea с одним или несколькими QX11EmbedContainer. По идее прелоадер лучше показывать поверх всего этого, но в рамках QMainWindow.

Comment: @Emm я в проекте использую QStackedWidget и при необходимости переключаюсь между основным виджетом и индикатором.

Comment: спасибо, интересное решение. А у QStackedWidget визуально можно скрыть кнопки для переключения между страницами? Upd: спасибо, уже разобрался :)

Comment: Эти кнопки отображаются только в QT Designer.